# Cannot zip a flux and return null values. How can we discard an event pair passed into a flux?

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor, spring-webflux

Say that you have a set of `Flux` that you would like to zip together with a bifunction.

```
Flux<String> flux1 = Flux.just("A", "B", "C");
Flux<String> flux2 = Flux.just("D", "E", "F");
Flux.zip(flux1, flux2, this::zipString).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

> This bifunction below will return `null` if an object meets a certain constraint. So that we can possibly apply a filter after zipping the `Flux` together.

```
public String zipString(String a, String b) {
    if (a.equals("B"))
        return null;
    return a + b;
}
```

This strategy will end up throwing a `NullPointerException`.

```
Exception in thread "main" 
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.NullPointerException: The zipper returned a null value
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: The zipper returned a null value
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxZip$ZipCoordinator.drain(FluxZip.java:711)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(FluxZip.java:861)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray.subscribe(FluxArray.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray.subscribe(FluxArray.java:59)
```

EDIT: On a side note this will also occur will occur when you have a `Flux` containing a null.

```
Flux<String> flux2 = Flux.just(null, "B", "C");
```

So this leads me to ask. Why are `null` values prohibited from entering a Flux?

What are some potential strategies to mitigate the use case below:

> flux2 contains a value that we should discard, therefore the set should be discarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Felt like this should be revisited after some time dealing with reactive streams. There are two approaches that handle these cases more elegantly than a default value to be filtered downstream.

**Tuples** (Preferred and optimal)

```
Flux.zip(flux1,flux2)
     .filter(t -> !t.getT1().equals("B") || !t.getT2().equals("B"))
     .map(this::zipString)
     .subscribe(System.out::println)
```

**Zipping Strategy returning Optional**

```
public Optional<String> zipString(String a, String b) {
    if (a.equals("B"))
        return Optional.empty();
    return Optional.of(a + b);
}

Flux.zip(flux1, flux2, this::zipString)
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 5):

The reactive spec doesn't allow `null` in streams. Pick a constant like "n/a" and filter it out later.

https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#2-subscriber-code

> 13. Calling onSubscribe, onNext, onError or onComplete MUST return
>       normally except when any provided parameter is null in which case it
>       MUST throw a java.lang.NullPointerException to the caller